# Duration of approval process for Canadian transit visa?

Tags: visas, canada

How long can I expect to wait for approval or not of a Canadian transit visa?

I'm a Costa Rican citizen applying via Internet from Costa Rica.

Comment: Where are you applying from ?

Comment: @blackbird57 Costa Rica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It typically takes **13 days** to process a visa application from Costa Rica, if the application is not missing anything. The Canadian government publishes such information on [CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/index.asp#) but they don't list visitor and transit separately so I'm assuming in your case it might take less time than a regular visitor visa.

[image]